# How to call page content inside other page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, shortcode

I am using WordPress theme and created few pages. On the **About Us** page, I wish to load content of another page (with ID 1009)

I have found a code that will make a shortcode for me, I have place this code in `functions.php` via WordPress editor and it works perfect, except the content doesn't go exactly where I place the short code...

Let me show you:

This is the short code function code:

```
function get_post_page_content( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => null,
    'title' => false,
), $atts ) );

$the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id='.$id );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
        if($title == true){
        the_title();
    }
    the_content();
}
wp_reset_postdata();

}
add_shortcode( 'my_content', 'get_post_page_content' );
```

This is the actual page I like to call up the content:
http://www.behnam-design.com/tgfpizza/ueber-uns/impressum/

This is ABOUT US page and I want to load up the content under **Impressum** tab,
but when I paste the short code `[my_content id="1009"]` inside the tab the whole content comes up on top of this page:
http://www.behnam-design.com/tgfpizza/ueber-uns/

#### Question

1. Is there anyways around this? So I can just get rid of the function code and load up that page content?
2. If not, how do I make that page content to go where I want it to instead of right on the top of the page? (and YES, I have not place the short code on top of the page, I have placed it inside **Impressum** tab but it shows up on top of the **About Us** page.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Wordpress... i don't know, but you could also do this (see this as an alternative) ;

- just put a link "see that page"
- create a html page and insert an iframe inside wordpress works great, it is like embeding.

Comment: Hi, iframe works if i give it a url, the issue then will be the whole menu and logo will appear too !

Comment: iframe : i think you can specify an exact position inside a frame, so you might be able to not show the whole thing, a part could be hidden.

see that page : I was just refering to adding a simple link-url sending people back to another page in your site.

good luck :-)